# Do the concepts of "coupling" and "avoiding external dependence" have opposite goals?

Tags: oop, functional-programming

Am I understanding correctly that these two concepts have opposing goals?

1. "Coupling" (writing code that is interdependent with other code)
2. "Avoiding External Dependence" (writing code that depends only on itself)

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: They are opposites, but coupling is never a "goal".

Comment: Whether a dependency is external or internal to your application doesn't really matter for the concept of coupling.

Comment: @Bergi Well, I assume he means a module with no external dependencies. The module wouldn't be coupled to other modules.

Comment: Oh, I see. So coupling is not a goal. Does that mean that the relationship between the two concepts is more accurately described as: avoiding external dependence is a result of avoiding coupling?